# Cucumber converting TypeRegistryConfiguration to ParameterType annotation JAVA

Tags: cucumber, optional-parameters, cucumber-java

Since TypeRegistry `io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistry` is `@Deprecated` I have troubles declaring my parameter annotations, I have now idea how to transform them to the @ParameterType

I tried this

```
@ParameterType(value = ".*", name = "foo")
public String foo(String foo) {
    return "foobar";
}

@ParameterType("foo")
@When("I type {foo}")
public void iType(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

the step recognises this parameter and it compiles but I get following error:

```
io.cucumber.java.InvalidMethodSignatureException: A @ParameterType annotated method must have one of these signatures:
 * public Author parameterName(String all)
 * public Author parameterName(String captureGroup1, String captureGroup2, ...ect )
 * public Author parameterName(String... captureGroups)
at com.dsm.steps.RequestAccessSteps.withTheInformationIconContaining(java.lang.String)
Note: Author is an example of the class you want to convert captureGroups to
```

but honestly I dont understand what they are trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault is I put the `@Parametertype("foo")` above the step but thats not necessary and thus throwing the error. It works perfectly fine otherwise.

So this works:

```
public String foo(String foo) {
    return "foobar";
}

@When("I type {foo}")
public void iType(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```